# Regular Expressions Help in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression I'm using to remove html tags and now I'm wondering if there is any way to modify it so that it could also remove links beginning with `http` and ending with `.stm` or `.gif`?

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
string BBCSplit = Regex.Replace(BBC, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to figure out regular expressions is through example, trial and error.

Put your html text in [this site](http://regexpal.com/), along with your regexp and if it turns yellow, it's matched.

If you need a tutorial on how regexp works, I found [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to be very useful.

The regexp you'll want will be something like `http:.*\.stm` - which means "the characters http, followed by 0 or more characters (.*) followed by the characters .stm".